# why is my ArgumentMatcher never called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, mocking, mockito

I try to run the simplest test

with mockito argument matcher:

```
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyObject;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.argThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


     @Test
        public void test123() throws Exception {
            MyClient cofmanClient = mock(MyClient.class);
            cofmanClient.holy("zigzag");

            MyClient verify = verify(cofmanClient);
            verify.holy(argThat(new MyMatcher()));
        }

        private static class MyClient {
            public void holy(String s) {
                System.out.println("Called with: " + s);
            }
        }

        private static class MyMatcher extends ArgumentMatcher<String> {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Object argument) {
                System.out.println("Deadly cow! s=" + argument.getClass().getName());
                return argument.getClass() == Class.class;
            }
        }
```

however my matcher is never called.

what am i missing?

Comment: what if you remove the surrounding `argThat()` method call?

Comment: what does MyClient verify = verify(cofmanClient); do?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle `Error:(158, 21) java: incompatible types: mytype.MyMatcher cannot be converted to java.lang.String`

Comment: I just tested your code using Mockito 1.9.5 and it works fine, which Mockito version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public boolean matches(String argument)
```

Comment: Error:(167, 20) java: linqmap.supportool.services.gas.GasStationConfigServiceTest.MyMatcher is not abstract and does not override abstract method matches(java.lang.Object) in org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher

Comment: hum ok, my bad
i thoung it may work because of ArgumentMatcher<String>, since the "generic" was an string i would make sense if method was too.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that a break point in intellij over `"verify"` method blocks from stopping on breakpoint inside the `ArgumentMatcher`.